# Writing a script file to create a new folder based on the current date

Tags: scripting, backup

CentOS 5.3

I have a script file that works for backing up a repository and I am using rsync to copy the contents to the source directory.

I have a crontab job that runs every night at 12am that calls my script file. `repos_backup.sh`

```
rsync -razv dev@xx.xx.xx.xx:repos /home/backup_sys_user/repos_backup
```

However, this puts all the repositories in repos_backup directory. However, I am looking for a way to create a new directory based on the date the backup was done. So I should have a directory structure like this:

```
/repos_backup/10.10.2010
             /11.10.2010
             /12.10.2010
```

I haven't done much scripting before, is there anyway to do this.

Many thanks for any advice,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
date +%m.%d.%Y
```

To get the current date (e.g. 10.10.2010)

To include it within a command, you can do:

```
mkdir ~/myuser/`date +%m.%d.%Y`/backup
```

Note that the those are tick marks.